# simplyfing math in a string

Tags: php, exif

I am dealing with exif data acquired via php , and I see that the DPI of a scanned image can return 300/1 or 600/1 for example

I am not sure if this is normal  but google tells me it is common. I do not know if this means I may see 300/2 (150DPI)

When I get this variable from exif, I want to treat it as a math problem that needs simplifying or in math terms 300 / 1 =300 therefore 300. As it is a string I have no idea how to tell php to simplify the math in the string.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are dozens of duplicate questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+evaluate+math+expression+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRhMfq9engAhWCxIMKHadOAoAQrQIoBDAAegQIChAM&biw=2560&bih=1329

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the string contains something like `300` It sounds like you're looking to cast your string to an integer with something like `(int)$exif_string`. If it contains something like `300/1`, you can use [`substr($exif_string, 0, 3)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to grab only the first three characters.

Once you have an integer variable, you can make your calculations on it:

```
$dpi = (int)substr($exif_string, 0, 3);
$dpi_value = $dpi / 300;
```

[`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) would be a possible alternative, though I would recommend against this, due to the fact that it can allow arbitrary execution of code.

Comment: The string contains something like `"300/1"`. You can't evaluate that by simply casting it to an integer.

Comment: Obsidian Age your first solution is noot viable with 1200/1. thats a problem.